# Change Intent Data of an Activity in History Stack

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack, android-navigation

I have an app that can handle ".arr" files. In order to do it, I add the proper parameters at the AndroidManifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.arr" android:mimeType="*/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Then, when opening this kind of file from a file explorer, I get the URI with:

```
Uri uri = intent.getData();
```

The problem is that at the History Stack, its saved the Intent with its data (the file). So, if I then close my app and re-open it from history, it detects again as if I were opening the file again.

I want to keep the app in the History Stack but without the information of the file!!

Comment: (More of a hack than a solution) you could save the name of the last opened file in the SharedPreferences, check if it exists when invoked, and setup based on that...